# Why does this code only work inside a function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this JavaScript that is not in a function:

```
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"];
numbers.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
numbers.push("here");
document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = numbers[0];
document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = numbers[1];
document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = numbers[2];
document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML = numbers[3];
document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML = numbers[4];
document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML = numbers[5];
document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML = numbers[6];
document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML = numbers[7];
document.getElementById("b9").innerHTML = numbers[8];
document.getElementById("b11").innerHTML = numbers[9];
document.getElementById("b12").innerHTML = numbers[10];
document.getElementById("b13").innerHTML = numbers[11];
document.getElementById("b14").innerHTML = numbers[12];
document.getElementById("b15").innerHTML = numbers[13];
document.getElementById("b16").innerHTML = numbers[14];
document.getElementById("b10").innerHTML = numbers[15];
document.getElementById("b10").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

but it doesn't work. I know that it works up to the end of line three, but none of the buttons (the buttons that have the ids b1, b2, b3...) say anything.

When I change it to this:

```
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"];
numbers.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
numbers.push("here");

function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = numbers[0];
    document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = numbers[1];
    document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = numbers[2];
    document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML = numbers[3];
    document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML = numbers[4];
    document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML = numbers[5];
    document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML = numbers[6];
    document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML = numbers[7];
    document.getElementById("b9").innerHTML = numbers[8];
    document.getElementById("b11").innerHTML = numbers[9];
    document.getElementById("b12").innerHTML = numbers[10];
    document.getElementById("b13").innerHTML = numbers[11];
    document.getElementById("b14").innerHTML = numbers[12];
    document.getElementById("b15").innerHTML = numbers[13];
    document.getElementById("b16").innerHTML = numbers[14];
    document.getElementById("b10").innerHTML = numbers[15];
    document.getElementById("b10").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

The function buttonClick is called when the user presses any of the buttons, and when I press one of the buttons, the words are added to the buttons. Does anyone know why it only works inside of the function and how to change it so that it works outside of the function too?

Comment: Where is your code in relation to the HTML? Probably what is happening is that your Javascript is executing before the DOM is finished loading so all those `.getElementById` calls fail because the associated element doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine it's because those elements are not in the DOM when that code is being run. You can put it in a `window.onload` event or use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function.

Alternatively you can stick this code in the `<head>` or right before the closing `</body>` tag and it should work.

Comment: So I just put **window.onload;** in the javascript after all of the document.getElementByIds?

Comment: No you'd put all that code inside the onload function like `window.onload = function () { /* your code */ };` - being that we can't see how you're loading your JS you might not even need the onload event handler, and can just use the `<head>` or `</body>` placement method to reduce the bloat.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM might not have finished rendering when the JS executes.

Put the JS at the end of the `<body>` tag. Then you won't need the function.

Or do the below if you're only looking for modern browser support. No jQuery needed!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  var numbers=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"];
  numbers.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
  numbers.push("here");
  document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML=numbers[0];
  document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML=numbers[1];
  document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML=numbers[2];
  document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML=numbers[3];
  document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML=numbers[4];
  document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML=numbers[5];
  document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML=numbers[6];
  document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML=numbers[7];
  document.getElementById("b9").innerHTML=numbers[8];
  document.getElementById("b11").innerHTML=numbers[9];
  document.getElementById("b12").innerHTML=numbers[10];
  document.getElementById("b13").innerHTML=numbers[11];
  document.getElementById("b14").innerHTML=numbers[12];
  document.getElementById("b15").innerHTML=numbers[13];
  document.getElementById("b16").innerHTML=numbers[14];
  document.getElementById("b10").innerHTML=numbers[15];
  document.getElementById("b10").style.backgroundColor="white";
});
```

Comment: FYI `DOMContentLoaded` is not supported in IE8 and lower so use with caution if you're supporting legacy IE.

Comment: Yup.. That's why mentioned the 'modern browser' thingy.